# Communicating with a IP whitelisted service with EKS

Tags: networking, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have set up an EKS cluster using eksctl using all the default settings and now need to communicate with an external service which uses IP whitelisting. Obviously requests made to the service from my cluster come from whichever node the request was made from, but the list of nodes (and their ips) can and will change frequently so I cannot supply a single IP address for them to whitelist. After looking into this I found that I need to use a NAT Gateway.

I am having some trouble getting this to work, I have tried setting AWS_VPC_K8S_CNI_EXTERNALSNAT to true however doing so prevents all outgoing traffic on my cluster, I assume because the return packets do not know where to go so I never get the response. I've tried playing around with the route tables to no avail.

Any assistance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can follow [this guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html) to create public subnets and private subnets in your VPC.

Then create NAT gateways in public subnets. Also run all EKS nodes in private subnets. The pods in K8S will use NAT gateway to access the internet services.

Comment: After reconfiguring my auto scaling group to create nodes on the private subnets instead of the public ones I can now see that outgoing requests are in fact coming from the NAT Gateway IP which is correct, however in doing so my application is no longer accessible from the web.

My end goal here is to have my publicly accessible web application make requests to a certain IP address always come from one IP

Comment: @JazzyP Use Ingress to expose the services in your K8S cluster

Comment: false alarm, it does actually seem to be publicly accessible through the ELB even when the nodes are on the private subnet, so it looks like simply moving the nodes to the private subnet has sorted it, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Needed to do the same and I found that `eksctl` tool have flag `--node-private-networking` which is making all communication via NAT, so IP remains the same for all external calls.

```
eksctl create cluster \
    --name production \
    --version 1.14 \
    --nodegroup-name kube-workers \
    --node-type t3.medium \
    --nodes 3 \
    --nodes-min 1 \
    --nodes-max 5 \
    --node-ami auto \
    --node-private-networking \
    --ssh-access
```